# Install package in Centos 6 from Centos 7 repo

Tags: centos, cifs, packages

I have Centos 6 and Centos 7 machines setup so that the first uses mount.cifs in order to mount volumes from the second through a proprieraty software.

The problem is that the Centos 6 version of cifs-utils (which provides mount.cifs) is much older than the version Centos 7 have and thus the prorietaty software fails to mount cifs volumes with an error saying "kernel: CIFS: Unknown mount option "domainname=."

Clearly, the mount options in the cifs-utils version in Centos 7 have changed since the version Centos 6 have.

I cannot easily upgrade Centos 6 to Centos 7.

Will I break things if I add the Centos 7 repo to Centos 6 and update cifs-utils with its dependecies so that both machines run the same version?

Is there any other way?

EDIT: so I just realized that I have another Centos 7 machine that seems to work fine with the mysterious proprietary software that I'm trying to avoid naming. The only difference between the two 7's is that I ran yum update on the first one which among others also lifted cifs-utils, nfs-utils and samba a minor version up. I was able to downgrade all but samba which complains a lot about missing packages. I am pretty sure that the new samba broke something.

Comment: If you can modify the script which mounts your fileshares, could you try just `domain=` instead of `domainname=`?

Comment: This is not easy to do as there is no single script to edit but a big proprietary package. Tried to find where the cifs options are read from with no avail.

Comment: `grep -ir "domainname=" /path/to/bigpropietarysoftware`

Comment: That's exactly how I searched. It find a single binary .so file, which grep -a shows as garbadge.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid naming this software? We recommend against this. Things like that should always be named explicitly whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you don't break the systems, it's not a good idea to add repos from more recent versions of Centos. The backports repos are provided specifically to address this problem.

In my Centos 7.4 I see that mount.cifs has the option (man mount.cifs) 'domain' instead of 'domainname'. You should compare mount options from two systems and replace them with corresponding. I don't think that a system with EOL in 2020 may not have some common abilities.

Comment: I know that the option is "domain" in the new mount.cifs but I can't find where this is set as "domainname" in the proprietary software. Could be hardcoded.

Comment: How this proprietary software named? It's difficult to give more advices without other details.